# Looking for an elegant way to convert a copy book in Swift in Java

Tags: java, if-statement, cobol, copybook

I'm doing a conversion from a COBOL copybook to a SWIFT message. First I'm parsing the copybook with a copybookHelper class and then I write a giant set of if statements to test all the fields and populate my SWIFT string. Is there a less cumbersome way to implement it (without the gigantic set of ifs)?

SWIFT = Society for Worldwide Interbank Financial Telecommunication

Answer (score 1):

Would an `Enum` of the different message types help? With an enumeration in place, parsing a particular type and populating the swift string could be as simple as:

```
SwiftMessage msg = Enum.valueOf(SwiftMessage.class, "MT001");
msg.populateString(/* parameters? */);
```

An example of how you would write the enum implementation:

```
enum SwiftMessage { 
    MT001,
    MT002 { void populateString() { /* override implementation */ } },
    ...
    void populateString() { /* default implementation */ }
}
```

It's hard to be more specific without any details of what you are trying to do.